# How does Google Chrome installer work?

Tags: google-chrome, installation

I have been wondering - how does Google Chrome install in a single click?
http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?hl=en&brand=CHMB&utm_campaign=en&utm_source=en-ha-na-us-sk&utm_medium=ha&installdataindex=homepagepromo
Its not ClickOnce (that behaves differently) and this works cross browser. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

It actually is ClickOnce.

```
 function installViaClickOnce(opt_navDocument) {
    queueThankyou(10000, '\x26clickonceinstalled=', opt_navDocument);
    downloadInstaller(areStatsEnabled(), _GU_buildClickOncePath, "/update2/installers/clickonce/GoogleInstaller_en.application");
    showThrobber(true);
 }
```

Google's ClickOnce application installs the installer for Chrome which in turn does the download for the browser.

Answer (score 7):

Actually it is indeed bootstrapped with the ClickOnce installer.  It uses ClickOnce to get it's components onto the machine and then installs the rest of chrome via the downloaded components.